# Не могу подключиться к Java серверу в Heroku

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, исключения, heroku

Я осуществил сервер на Java, используя подключение через сокеты

Server.java (Залит на heroku):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server implements TCPConnectionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Server();
    }

    private final ArrayList<TCPConnection> connections = new ArrayList<>();

    private Server(){
        System.out.println("Старт сервера...");
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6969)){
            while (true){
                try{
                    new TCPConnection(this, serverSocket.accept());
                }catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Ошибка подключения: " + e);
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        connections.add(tcpConnection);
        sendToAllConnections(String.format("Клиент %s подключён", tcpConnection));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
        sendToAllConnections(value);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        connections.remove(tcpConnection);
        sendToAllConnections(String.format("Клиент %s отключён", tcpConnection));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка: " + e);
    }

    private void sendToAllConnections(String value){
        System.out.println("Всем:" + value);
        for (TCPConnection connection : connections) connection.sendString(value);
    }
}
```

TCPConnection.java (Залит на heroku):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TCPConnection {
    private final Socket socket;
    private final Thread thread;
    private final BufferedReader in;
    private final BufferedWriter out;
    private final TCPConnectionListener eventListener;

    public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, String ip, int port) throws IOException{
        this(eventListener, new Socket(ip, port));
    }

    public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener connectionListener, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.eventListener = connectionListener;
        this.socket = socket;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    eventListener.onConnectionReady(TCPConnection.this);
                    while (!thread.isInterrupted()){
                        eventListener.onReceiveString(TCPConnection.this, in.readLine());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
                } finally {
                    eventListener.onDisconnect(TCPConnection.this);
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void sendString(String value){
        try {
            out.write(value + "\r\n");
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void disconnect(){
        thread.interrupt();
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TCPConnection: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort();
    }
}
```

TCPConnectionListener.java (Залит на heroku):

```
public interface TCPConnectionListener {
    void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection);
    void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value);
    void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection);
    void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e);
}
```

Client.java (Находится на компьютере):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client implements TCPConnectionListener{
    private static String IP;

    static {
        try {
            IP = String.valueOf(InetAddress.getByName("floating-fortress-13537.herokuapp.com"));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final int PORT = 6969;
    private TCPConnection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Client().connect();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void connect(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            connection = new TCPConnection(this, IP, PORT);
            while (true) {
                String msg = in.nextLine();
                connection.sendString(msg);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            printMsg("Connection exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        printMsg("Connection ready...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
        printMsg(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
        printMsg("Connection closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
        printMsg("Connection exception: " + e);
    }

    private void printMsg(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

Сами логи heroku:

```
2021-01-03T19:06:38.226265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=6969 -cp target/classes/:target/dependency/* ru.romatopotato.Server`
2021-01-03T19:06:40.825920+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-01-03T19:06:40.831870+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-01-03T19:06:41.062579+00:00 app[web.1]: Старт сервера...
2021-01-03T19:06:42.608269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-03T19:06:42.596129+00:00 app[web.1]: Клиент /10.109.150.111: 48221 подключён
2021-01-03T19:06:42.596806+00:00 app[web.1]: Ошибка: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
2021-01-03T19:06:42.597172+00:00 app[web.1]: Клиент /10.109.150.111: 48221 отключён
2021-01-03T19:06:42.599599+00:00 app[web.1]: Клиент /172.19.96.17: 48199 подключён
2021-01-03T19:06:42.599942+00:00 app[web.1]: Ошибка: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
2021-01-03T19:06:42.600196+00:00 app[web.1]: Клиент /172.19.96.17: 48199 отключён
```

Весь код слизан с просторов Интернета дабы понять работу сокетов.
При этом сам Client.java я не запускаю, хотя логи показывают, будто кто-то подключается.

Но при попытке подключения к серверу самому (Запуска Client.java с компьютера) выскакивает исключение:

```
Connection exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: floating-fortress-13537.herokuapp.com/3.224.58.229
```

Где floating-fortress-13537.herokuapp.com - адрес моего приложения в heroku.
Хотелось бы получить ответы на вопросы: Как подключиться к своему серверу? Вообще можно ли в Хероку подключаться через сокеты? Если можно, то что я делаю неправильно? Если нельзя, то какой сервис (желательно бесплатный, для тестов) можно использовать для этого? Заранее благодарю

Comment: чтобы понять работу сокетов, лучше запустить все локально, потому как выбранный вами порт с высокой ворятностью будет заблокирован каким-то фаерволом или еще чем-то подобным...

Comment: @Дмитрий, получается сокеты только для одной сети? Не моги бы вы подсказать, каким образом стоит подключаться к таком вот серверу? Я читал про WebSockets, но, кажется, они не подходят для этого. Первоначально моя идея заключалась в онлайн чате в режиме реального времени, с фуекцией передачи Я изучаю сетевое программирование чтобы в конечном итоге создать онлайн игру, и для передачи данных решил использовать сокеты через удалённый сервер, но, похоже, просчитался

Comment: открывать порты, либо использовать открытые. это не настолько простой вопрос, чтобы односложно на него ответить. кроме того, если вы хотите чат, то как раз вебсокеты вам подойдут идеально. по сути для клиент-серверного соединения вебсокетов (если требуется обратная связь сервера с клиентом) либо http-запросы (если таковая не требуется) более чем достаточно